# Are there QFTs in which a field cannot produce a real particle?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

The usual mantra of a quantum field theory is that real particles (as opposed to virtual ones) are excitations of a field.

Is this a necessary property of *all* (operator-valued) quantum field theories? Are there any theories currently in existence whose fields do not or cannot produce real particles?

Comment: Matt Strassler article [here](http://profmattstrassler.com/2013/09/24/quantum-field-theory-string-theory-and-predictions-part-2/) discusses this.  There are many QFTs that don't have any particles.

Comment: Howard Georgi has written some articles over the last few years about "unparticle physics".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

In a two-dimensional Yang-Mills gauge theory, the Faddeev-Popov ghosts kill two possible excitations of the gauge field (same as always), leaving no possible excitations that we would characterize as *particles*. There are no gauge bosons in such a theory. (There *are* global "excitations" though, analogous to instantons, but they are not *particles*)

Yet, it is not a fully trivial theory, as there are still observables - the so-called *Wilson lines* - and the partition function depends on the topological structure of the two-dimensional "spacetime".

Such a theory does not directly describe any physical system, though.

Comment: Also, conformal field theories don't have particle excitations.